# Can a Google Apps Script edit another Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Can you work with scripts like you can with Docs, Spreadsheets and Forms? ie. I can copy a Document by using DocsList.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy, and then edit the copy with DocumentApp.openById(fileId).getBody.replaceText.

Copying the file (per above) will also create a copy of the associated script, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent ScriptApp...replaceText (there is a ScriptApp, but it does different things). Is there any way to programmatically edit a script?

I want users to be able to run a script that will copy my script and customise it for them, based on some input they provide to my script.

Answer (score 2):

Apps Scripts projects can be imported and exported with the Google Drive SDK:

[Documentation Import/Export](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export)

The Google Drive SDK can be run from Apps Script, but you need to explicitly enable it.

[Documentation enabling Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

It looks like you can't edit a project file, so you would need to do any custom editing in a document, save the file, then retrieve the contents of the file into a variable, and then use the variable in the `source` parameter for the contents of a new apps script file to be created.

[Documentation Create New Files in a Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export#create_new_files_within_a_project)

So, there are no methods in a service to directly do what you want.  Not like editing a Doc.  You'd need to either export the current file from your project, then import it into their project, or have a copy of the current Apps Script file in a Document that you then retrieved, and wrote to their new project file.

Comment: Thank-you! So I can replace the script rather than editing it, which gets me where I want to be (with a little less elegance). Will test it out and respond.

Comment: i wouldnt recommend this route. simply use a single library for all and parametrize your code ao that it can be customized by storing preferences (in script properties).