# Use app script to change/edit a function on a different app script file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that I use in multiple app scripts attached to multiple google sheets, I was wondering if I can change/edit this function in all the sheets at once using a function on a new app script?

Meaning I want to be able to edit the function on a sheet from another sheet, is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Google Apps Script edit another Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880637/can-a-google-apps-script-edit-another-script)

Comment: You can write  a script with Apps Script API that can replace all or any of the function in a project.

Comment: I think according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51188688/13771937) you can, but only through the Apps Script API (not through Apps Script itself). I would recommend if you find yourself using the same functions across GAS projects that you deploy them as a library that you share across files though.